# How to efficiently format data of multiple columns in SAS

Tags: sas, formatting, multiple-columns

I am working in SAS and want to change the type and format of multiple columns. For example, some I want to convert to a number variable with a format length of 3 and others to a character variable with a format length of 41.

Currently I am creating a column and specifying the format I would like. I then copy the data in the original column into the new column so it takes on the new format.

**Here is the code:**

```
DATA CAUSE1;
    SET Temp.MstCause;
    FORMAT CauseDescrs $CHAR30.;
    CauseDescrs = CauseDescr;
    Drop CauseDescr;
RUN;

DATA CAUSE;
    SET CAUSE1;
    FORMAT CauseDescr $41.;
    CauseDescr = CauseDescrs;
    Drop CauseDescrs;
RUN;
```

Does anyone know of a more efficient way of formatting the columns.

Comment: Can you add to your question the output from `Proc CONTENTS data=Temp.MstCause order=varnum` ? You appear to be doing type conversions using implicit type conversion during value assignment. What would be the reason for doing this type conversion ?  Formats are a recipe for producing a value representation in output.  'Converting' is more often the term for changing the underlying value type.  A numeric of length 3 is the number of bytes used to store the number as a IEEE floating point representation on disk.  Is the length '3' in the question really the variables format ?

Comment: Are you changing types (numeric to char) or just formats, so say $8 to $4.? Formats and types are different and you would use different approaches.

Comment: Thanks guys for bringing to my attention the difference between format and types. Richard I am changing the format and types so they are consistent with the previous data. Recently the data was moved from being stored on SAS to Sql which changed the format. I have no control over how that move is done. For simplicity I just want to create a code that makes sure that the format and type of the new data is the same as the old.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way is usually `proc datasets`, e.g.:

```
proc datasets lib = temp;
modify mstcause;
format causedescr $char30. anothervar 8.; /*...add more variables & formats here*/
run;
quit;
```

You can also apply formats at the point when you're processing the data, e.g. by adding a format statement to a `proc means` or some other statistical proc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're changing the variable *type* or *length*, and not just the applied format, then you must use a data step and assignment.  You don't have to use *two* data steps, though, that's unnecessary; and you could use a data step view, if this is an intermediate step (i.e., it's not the final deliverable file).

The way I usually do it is like this:

```
*Change character to numeric;
data want;
  set have(rename=var=var_c);
  var = input(var_c,informat.);
run;

*Increase length of character variable;
data want;
  length var $40;
  set have;
run;
```

If you're only changing the *format*, and not the *length*, then you can do that in `proc datasets`.  It can change most any dataset metadata, but cannot change the actual stored length (which requires rewriting the whole dataset).  I doubt that's what you're doing in the above example (as you're using the default format, and increasing it), though; you're probably changing the *length*.

Note that *length* for a character variable is the number of characters that can be stored; while *format* controls how it's shown on the screen (but not what's stored).  Applying a format to a prior undeclared variable will set its length to that of the format, but the length and the format are two mostly unrelated things.